# How can I get codeigniter captcha image Library

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I get codeigniter captcha image library. configuration erquired to define `'img_path' => '', 'img_url' => '',` but I don't have such folder or images,  I red soo many tutorials and codeigniter documentation as well .. but no one describe where that captcha library located..

**Function**

```
public function captcha() {
        /* Set a few basic form validation rules */
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', "Name", 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', "Captcha", 'required');

        /* Get the user's entered captcha value from the form */
        $userCaptcha = set_value('core/captcha');

        /* Get the actual captcha value that we stored in the session (see below) */
        $word = $this->session->userdata('captchaWord');



        /* Check if form (and captcha) passed validation */
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE &&
                strcmp(strtoupper($userCaptcha), strtoupper($word)) == 0) {
            /** Validation was successful; show the Success view * */
            /* Clear the session variable */
            $this->session->unset_userdata('captchaWord');


            /* Get the user's name from the form */
            $name = set_value('name');

            /* Pass in the user input to the success view for display */
            $data = array('name' => $name);
            $this->load->view('pages/captcha-success-view', $data);
        } else {

            /** Validation was not successful - Generate a captcha * */
            /* Setup vals to pass into the create_captcha function */
            $vals = array(
                'word' => 'Random word',
                'img_path' => '',
                'img_url' => '',
                'img_width' => '150',
                'img_height' => 30,
                'expiration' => 7200
            );

            print_r($vals);

            /* Generate the captcha */
            $captcha = create_captcha($vals);

            $data['captcha'] = $captcha;
            $data['image'] = $captcha['image'];

            /* Store the captcha value (or 'word') in a session to retrieve later */
            $this->session->set_userdata('captchaWord', $captcha['word']);

            /* Load the captcha view containing the form (located under the 'views' folder) */
            $this->load->view('pages/captcha-view', $data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you have load captcha helper or what error u got ?

Comment: Is it only captcha helper... no image folder??

Comment: your have to mention your folder path here 'img_path' => '',

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no captcha library in CodeIgniter but helper. All you have to do load this helper first to use captcha `$this->load->helper('captcha');`

And remember, you must need to create a folder in your project where CI will put captcha images. So if you create a folder name 'captcha' in your project root then your code will be (demo)

```
$this->load->helper('captcha');
$vals = array(
 'img_path' => 'captcha/',
 'img_url' => base_url('captcha'),
 'font_path' => 'assets/fonts/ALGER.TTF',
 'img_width' => '300',
 'img_height' => 80,
 'font_size' => 24,
 'colors' => array(
    'background' => array(255, 255, 255),
    'border' => array(0, 0, 0),
    'text' => array(0, 0, 0),
    'grid' => array(255, 40, 40)
  )
);

$cap = create_captcha($vals);
```

Now print your captcha wherever you want `echo $cap['image']`